# Why this function is not returning [0,0,7]?

Tags: python, list, return, append

Why it's returning False instead of True? What's wrong with my code? Why it isn't returning [0,0,7]?

```
model_neschimbat = [0,0,7]
def spy2(lista):
    
    ce_a_iesit = []
    model = [0, 0, 7]
    model_neschimbat = [0,0,7]
    for i in range(0,len(lista) - 1):
        if lista[i] == model[0]:
            ce_a_iesit.append(lista[i])
            model.pop(0)
    print(ce_a_iesit)
    if ce_a_iesit == model_neschimbat:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, add it in as formatted text

Comment: Which part of your code did you expect to make the function return [0, 0, 7]?

Comment: the print part should print [0, 0, 7], and it should return True

Comment: This function returns `True` or `False`.  There is no way it could return `[0,0,7]` as stated in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the model variable inside the loop, so it is not the same as model_neschimbat when the loop ends.
You can use list.copy() to create a copy of the list:

```
model = [0, 0, 7]
model_neschimbat = model.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the for loop, specifically

```py
for i in range(0,len(lista) - 1):
```

You are going from [0, len(lista) - 1), which means that you skip the last element. Just change `len(lista) - 1` to `len(lista)`.

TLDR; the upper bound in a Python for loop is exclusive.

Comment: but if I start from 0, shouldn't it be len(x) - 1 ?

Comment: You want to start from 0 (first element) to ``len(x) - 1`` (last element) indeed. However, Python considers the ``len(x) - 1`` part as exclusive, which means that it will stop just before that, which is  ``len(x) - 2``.